# Executing method before loading view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an application on CodeIgniter that generate a PDF report using some information. Before doing that, I need to execute a function in a controller to save data on the database. I called the methods on the controller using JavaScript. How can I call the function before redirecting to the PDF controller? I have this:

```
    window.open("codeIgniterURL/Controller1/function1",'_self',false);
    window.open("codeIgniterURL/Controller2/function2",'_self',false);
```

So what I need to do, is to call a function of  controller1 within a view before opening the Window of Controller 2. What I do now is to open the Controller1 with a window.open, and in that controller redirect to the view where I invoked the method, but its not working like I need.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: save the data.... then load the view/give the output. i don't see what is the exact problem here....

Comment: hi are you using same data to view as report in pdf which you are saving just let me know?

Comment: The problem is that I need to save the data by clicking a button inside a view, and then generate the PDF on that same view. The same button have to do both thing, first save, then show data. When I execute window.open to save the data and return to the view, all the data is lost. Any way to save the data without having to do a window.open?

Comment: I just thought about a dirty way of doing this. In the controller that writes the PDF, just before doing the PDF stuff, call the other controller that save data to the database. Not sure if this will work, but I will give a try and post my result here.

Answer (score 1):

If this helps, I accomplished this by using two controllers, a model, and an Ajax call.

In Controller 1, I have the code that writes the PDF.

Controller 2 makes the call to the model to write to the database. Then it instantiates Controller 1, uses ghostScript to create an image of the generated PDF, and sets the name of the PDF in a session variable.

In my view, I use Ajax to send the post data to Controller 2, then, using the session variable, it dynamically displays the image created and a download button for the PDF.